# SVM a dataframe based on the last column

Tags: r, dataframe, svm

I'm trying since hours and hours to svm a dataframe based on the last class name.

I have this data frame

```
#FIll the data frame
df = read.table("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data",
               sep=",",
               col.names=c("buying", "maint", "doors", "persons", "lug_boot", "safety", ""),
               fill=TRUE,
               strip.white=TRUE)

lastColName <- colnames(df)[ncol(df)]
```

...

```
model <- svm(lastColName~.,
             data = df,
             kernel="polynomial",
             degree = degree,
             type = "C-classification",
             cost = cost)
```

I'm getting either `NULL` or `Error in model.frame.default(formula = str(lastColName) ~ ., data = df1,  :  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'str(lastColName)'`. I understand that `NULL` arrives when the column hasn't a name. I don't understand the other error since it's the last column name..

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `as.formula` when you are trying to use dynamic variable in the formula. For details see `?as.formula`

The following code works fine:

```
library(e1071)
df_1 = read.table("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data",
                sep=",",
                col.names=c("buying", "maint", "doors", "persons", "lug_boot", "safety", ""),
                fill=TRUE,
                strip.white=TRUE)

lastColName <- colnames(df_1)[ncol(df_1)]

model <- svm(as.formula(paste(lastColName, "~ .", sep = " ")),
             data = df_1,
             kernel="polynomial",
             degree = 3,
             type = "C-classification",
             cost = 1)
# to predict on the data remove the last column 
prediction <- predict(model, df_1[,-ncol(df_1)])

# The output
table(prediction)

# The output is:

prediction
acc  good unacc  vgood 
0     0    1728     0 

# Since this is a highly unbalanced classification the model is not doing a very good job
```

Comment: Wow, thank it works ! However, the prediction fails by saying that the arguments aren't from the same lenght.. I used your method => `table(predict(model), as.formula(paste(lastColName, "~ .", sep = " ")), dnn=c("Prediction", "Actual"))`

Comment: Updated the answer to predict from the model.